# Why my jquery post inside another function is sending multiple times?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm working in a simple jquery post. I have a list of objects and when the user clicks a object in the list, I change some js vars for make a post request with this data. This is my html code.

```
<ul>
    <li data-selected-option="1">
        <a herf="javascript:void(0)" class="option">1</a>
    </li>
    <li data-selected-option="2">
        <a herf="javascript:void(0)" class="option">2</a>
    </li>
    <li data-selected-option="3">
        <a herf="javascript:void(0)" class="option">3</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="modal fade" id="optionmodalsettings" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="optionmodalsettings" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
    ...
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="send_option_post">Send</a>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code.

```
$(function () {
    var post_url ="my_post_url";

    $(".option").on('click', function () {
        $('#optionmodalsettings').modal();
        var selected_option = $(this).closest('li').data('selected-option');

        $('.send_option_post').on('click', function() {
            $.post(update_website_noty_url, {selected_option: selected_option}, function (response) {
                $('#optionmodalsettings').data('modal', null);
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    });
})
```

Whean a user hit an element of the list, I change the selected_option var via javascript and open a boostrap modal. With the bootstrap modal opened, a user can hit the button .send_option_post inside the modal for make a post request sending as parameter the selected_option var. At the first time all runs fine but, if a user click anocther element and sends the post request, then the post is sent two times, and if the user hit again an element in the list and click the .send_option_post, the request is sent three times, and must be only post request by click. Why is happenig that? Thank you so much.

Comment: You have a typo: `herf=` should be `href=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the user clicks on `.option`, you're adding another click handler to `.send_option_post`. So if the user clicks on 3 options, then clicks on `.send_option_post`, it will post 3 times.

You should bind the `.send_option_post` click handler just once, not every time the user clicks on `.option`. Move the `selected_option` variable to an outer scope of both functions.

```
$(function () {
    var post_url ="my_post_url";
    var selected_option;

    $(".option").on('click', function () {
        $('#optionmodalsettings').modal();
        selected_option = $(this).closest('li').data('selected-option');

    });
    $('.send_option_post').on('click', function() {
        if (selected_option === undefined) {
            alert("You need to select an option first");
        } else {
            $.post(update_website_noty_url, {selected_option: selected_option}, function (response) {
                $('#optionmodalsettings').data('modal', null);
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
});
```